# Center image between containers while keeping responsivity

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add an image on top of the other and keep the responsivity? Basically what I need is an image that is centered between one image and a container. I am using Bootstrap.

Attached screenshot.

I tried different variants with `float`, `position: absolute;` and so on but nothing seemed to work when the screen was being resized.

Tried finding info about this but frankly I have no idea how to formulate the problem so that I find an answer.

[image: screenshot]

Link: http://euro-tax.connectmedia.ro/

Comment: Can you please provide link?

Comment: http://euro-tax.connectmedia.ro/

Comment: @LaljiTadhani the HTML is pretty irrelevant. I'm more interested in the general way to do it than in this particular case so that I can learn something from it and maybe solve other people's problem as well. Anyway, I provided the link, you can use inspect element. Thanks! :)

Comment: do you want it at center of screen

Comment: @arsh_kalsi not really, I want it in the middle of the 8 columns (col-md-8) to the left. The form is in a col-md-4.

Answer (score 2):

With `position:absolute` you can use `calc` property to define position of an element. You just need to do some calculation. In you case I'm setting `left:calc(50% - 21px)`, it means `50% - half-width of element`. This will set position of element in center of any parent element in any viewport.

```css
div{
  position:relative;
}
.absoluteImage{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:15px;
  left:calc(50% - 21px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img style="width:100%" src="http://euro-tax.connectmedia.ro/wp-content/themes/euro-tax/images/xheader-bg.jpg.pagespeed.ic.CWwqtcTBRJ.jpg">
  
  <img class="absoluteImage" src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGRm4BAABXRUJQVlA4TGEBAAAvKkAFEF9CEAgSyftj7TIEQbZNQeYv9oMQZNuUeee4s8K2bdtcZDvdzaxar35AAAIAIBAEwzCCBjA2jEAwGgcgGGiA4GMhmGgIDwIwGgMDD4IAggYwwAQAgRBMAKNhBEAQeEBsJEmRVL3H/H/MzMxMz9D++7MwPbsmRPQ/YdZuP4skvJOdnP/c6mQaXbavGXgmK3Nlu2sMWXkvwyuZpTdWhp+s/jXhkZp/rH5uWA588OLrs9wkdixnEbhHZiy3CYSnLA8puKX2LKdhgmn0WN6z0GfvLHsGmbAb3yw+KtBVPlh8N8iGU3yy+G9Btv5ZPIvkQElfWI78cPwjlpc0KVDja5bLKKzokuU6TipEcMLylA/lTywnQRKQRoe9dQyS0NW+2P2rRjpoCw92exRAOuhfz6w/v8AkHVxiK9atYrBIB7fAmOU4AJt0cG+z2oZCOniofrD1UYVKOnjJHX+POQjSAQA=" >
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Move the anchor out of `.bannerbox` like HTML shown below and add class `show-more` to it.

> For responsive view adjust the `background-position` value of `.bannerhead`  and
>   `.show-more` class value to get the desired result in mobile view using
>   media queries.

HTML:

```
<div class="bannerbox col-md-8">
  <h1>Recuperarea Taxelor si 
                Alocatiilor din strainatate</h1>

  <p style="font-weight:300;">Ai obtinut venituri din strainatate? Înseamna ca poti obtine restituirea impozitelor platite acolo.<br> Dar si alocatiile europene, ori alte taxe si asigurari pot fi recuperate. Afla acum ce drepturi ai si solicita înapoisuma maxima posibila.</p>

</div>
<a href="#section2" rel="m_PageScroll2id" class="_mPS2id-h mPS2id-highlight mPS2id-highlight-first mPS2id-highlight-last show-more"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACsAAAAWCAMAAABuZ5WBAAAA5FBMVEXjHnL////jHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnLjHnL1kVINAAAAS3RSTlMAAAEDBAYHCAkNDxEUFxoeIyQnMDM3OTxBS0xQVltcYG11eYCFh5OVlpmepKq2uLq7v8TFyMnQ0dLW2Nzj5Ofs7/P09vj5+vv8/f6BxUE3AAABG0lEQVQoz43T11bCYBAE4NlQpKN0hUhXqlIs9GIowr7/+3hBsqSQHPcqM/Odk6sfgLo8vifgdkREibfj8pkISoOZeZH2sOkFM3NDQYuZmfnnydU+bi+khd3lg08VF1s56WKHMRv36rtBfS+yjxH/lNAPO2i4L+tHHAj1JH4nbTT5JVsvRACUphSrjIVmVrI0FSIAQPlgVFrRRIuaUR/KRLpFYWO056rQ6tkoNwW6WqTm8re2HwDgb0szT5HZIjaSaRABEBlIHsXIahHsyjjN3eWmkrpBslsodb51dYWcFlD3DrlXiW5a5Nc2us7DzeJhZqGze7hbRIcmOozCyyLQEdoJwNsCNZ3Wrm/I1aKkMbNWwn8sspPfSRZO+wc672iCowb7mQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
    class="center-block" style="padding-bottom:10px;" data-pagespeed-url-hash="1407470906" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.bannerhead {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/euro-tax/images/xheader-bg.jpg.pagespeed.ic.CWwqtcTBRJ.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 68%;
  position: relative;
}

.show-more {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `position:relative` inside your parent element

```
div.bannerhead {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then set child element like this:

```
<div classs="bannerhead">
    <img class="center-block" src="" >
</div>
```

Now set CSS for `absolute` or child element something like this:

```
img.center-block {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -30px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;  
   margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 99;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can apply this rule inside each new element.
I have tested to apply this rule and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a grid layout. Creating a containing div and place your container, image and image as children. Than use the grid-layout properties to center them.

**Html**

```
<div id="grid-container">
  <img src="#" id="img1">
  <img src="#" id="center-img">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1;
  grid-template-columns: auto 10px auto;
}

center-img {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

**Note:** This will not work for any browser currently because the grid-layout feature must be manually enabled.